Use environment variable for docker cli arguments with docker compose
On the HPC cluster I work with, I'm expected to use an environment variable with docker containers to link the container gpu device to the allocated gpu.
docker run -it ${DOCKER_GPU_ARGUMENTS} --rm image bash

Expends to:
docker run -it --memory=64g --memory-swap=64g --gpus all --device=/dev/nvidia-uvm --device=/dev/nvidia-uvm-tools --device=/dev/nvidiactl  --device /dev/nvidia0 --rm image bash

Is there a way to use that environment variable with docker-compose ?

Yes, read the documentation for the deploy property
The environment variable can't be formatted this way, you should probably have it in three variables, interpolated into the compose file

ok, so it's a "no" I guess… (of course, I know I can achieve the expected behaviour by setting the memory and devices options in the docker-compose.yml file, but I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to split it manually. I'd like to pass it as is.)

Oh, my apologies, then the answer is no, you could use a small bash script to run the docker run command, but this really is what Docker Compose was made for
